# HTTPS-Request from Python Azure Function App with Client Certificate from Azure Key Vault

Tags: python, azure-functions, client-certificates

I would like to send an HTTPS-Request from a Python Azure Function App. I need to authenticate this request using a client certificate which is stored in an Azure Key Vault.

When testing the HTTPS-Request with the pkcs12 container loaded from disk, everything worked out:

```
from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter

url = 'https://example/api/profile'

with Session() as s:
    s.mount(url, Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_filename='cert.pfx', pkcs12_password='cert_password'))
    r = s.get(url, verify='ca_cert.pem')

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Turns out this is a little more complicated using a certificate from the KeyVault.

I tried fetching the pkcs12 cert object using the CertificateClient Class and the password using the SecretClient Class:

```
from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter
from azure.keyvault.certificates import CertificateClient

pkcs12_name = 'cert_name'
pkcs12_pass_name = 'cert_password_name'
vault_name = 'vault-name'

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

cert_client = CertificateClient("https://" + vault_name + ".vault.azure.net/", credential)
cert = cert_client.get_certificate(pkcs12_name)

secret_client = SecretClient("https://" + vault_name + ".vault.azure.net/", credential)
secret = secret_client.get_secret(pkcs12_pass_name)

# debugging
logging.info('--== PKCS12 DETAILS ==--')
logging.info(cert.name)
logging.info(cert.properties.version)
logging.info('--== SECRET DETAILS ==--')
logging.info(secret.name)
logging.info(secret.properties)
```

Which worked fine - I got the certificate as well as the password. But how do I pass it to the pkcs12-adapter as I did with the local files? I can't provide a filepath but I know that there is a parameter pkcs12_data which allows to read a byte stream.

```
with Session() as s:
    s.mount(url, Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_data=cert, pkcs12_password=secret)) # <---- how to pass cert?
    r = s.get(url, verify='ca_cert.pem')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below code with app registration client id, secrete, and tenant id to get the certificate and password from the key vault in functions.

**Code:**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

client_id = '<client_ID>'
client_secret = '<client_secrete>'
tenant_id = '<tenant_ID>'

vault_url = 'https://kamkeyvaul.vault.azure.net'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            tenant_id=tenant_id
        )

        client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credentials)
        certificate_secret = client.get_secret("<certificate_name>").value
        password_secret = client.get_secret("<password_secrete>").value

        logging.info("Certificate Secret: %s", certificate_secret)
        logging.info("Password Secret: %s", password_secret)

        return func.HttpResponse("Secrets retrieved successfully.", status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Internal Server Error", status_code=500)
```

**requirements.txt:**

```py
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-certificates
azure-keyvault-secrets
requests
requests_pkcs12
```

I gave the managed Identity **on** in **function app** at **Azure Portal** as below,

[image]

Before going to run the code, I gave access to **function app** and **app registration** to get the certificate and secrete password in **key vault** at **Azure Portal** as below,

[image]

**Output:**

It runs successfully and gives the certificate and password as below,

[image]

With the output **URL**, I got this at browser as below,

[image]

I got the **certificate** and **pasword** as below,

[image]